# DIV containing more than 100 floated divs caused the layout to break

Tags: html, css

I built a filtering system and had to integrate it in wordpress, the problem is that all the divs are floated left and this caused the layout to break, I've tryed clearing the parent div, tried the overflow method but couldn't figure that out.

The divs have to be displayed as block since the filtering script is working that way.

Here is the link to that page: http://www.raw-partner.de/wer-wir-sind/team-2/

One entry looks like this:

```
<div id="filtering">

<div class="entry" data-id="max-appelt" data-category="partner munchen steuerberater wirtschaftsprufer rechtsanwalte">
<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/maximilian-appelt-4/"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Appelt_P_0613_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Maximilian Appelt</b></h3></a>

</div>
```

this is the css for the entry class

```
.entry {
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;

}
```

Any idea how I could fix the broken rows?
Thanks!

Comment: edit script and use [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: not sure how to do that tbh

Comment: add your js script to question

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your height is set to auto. Give a fixed height to the class .entry. Something like height: 200px, just to see what happens. Seems to be working just fine if you change it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats for this type of layout. Use CSS Grid instead:

```
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.entry {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox, browser support is good [check](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

```css
#filtering {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

.entry {
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="filtering">

  <div class="entry" data-id="max-appelt" data-category="partner munchen steuerberater wirtschaftsprufer rechtsanwalte">
    <a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/maximilian-appelt-4/">
      <p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Appelt_P_0613_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
      <h3 id="name"><b>Maximilian Appelt</b></h3>
    </a>

  </div>
```